# How to detect visibility change in parent element using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've been using ExtendStudio's JQuery PowerSlider to rotate images on a web page and want to detect when a new image appears.  I've checked their HTML using the Chrome debugger and each slider image is always visible, but the parent div's opacity is adjusted by their slider code.

```
<div style="opacity: 0; "><img name="slide1_img" src="img1.jpg"></div>
<div style="opacity: 1; "><img name="slide2_img" src="img2.jpg"></div>
<div style="opacity: 0; "><img name="slide3_img" src="img3.jpg"></div> [etc...]
```

So ideally, I'd like a script that detects when the appropriate div is visible.  I'm new to web coding and jQuery so have reviewed approaches including .live(), .delegate(), and the livequery plug-in, but I'm not sure that I'm figuring any of them out 100%, but here's what I thought should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div:visible > img[name="slide2_img"]').livequery(function() {
        alert("Slide 2 is visible");
    });
});
```

I guess it could be any combination of problems with the selectors, livequery, syntax, or...  Also, I set a breakpoint on the second line of the script above and it it only seems to trigger once on doc ready.  I know livequery is old and apparently .live() and .delegate() can detect changes better, but the descriptions on the jQuery site didn't seem to address my scenario.

All suggestions are much appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Try looking into `is(":visible")` that might be something you are looking for.

Comment: Instead of `.live` or `.delegate`, [you'd use `.on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 0):

1. In projects don't use `:visible`, use `:not(:hidden)`
2. In terms of jQuery all divs are visible
3. You don't need to check visibility, you need to check `css('opacity')`. Use code below:

---

```
$('div > img[name="slide2_img"]').on('click',function(){
  var T = $(this), P = T.parent('div');
  if(P.css('opacity') == '0'){
    alert("Slide 2 is not visible");
  }
  else{
    alert("Slide 2 is visible");
  }
});
```